# running script with -o argument pointing to mount point of sd-card

Tags: scripting, mount, images, sd-card, angstrom

I was trying to install Angstrom Linux on Colibri T_30 board---but I am stuck at one point where it specifies that

> run update.sh script with optional -o argument pointing to mount point
>   of above mentioned card

Now, I am very confused as to what to put with the -o option. I searched on Google as `running script with -o option` and also as `running script with optional arguments` but couldn't find any helpful/satisfactory result.

My sd-card is mounted on my `CentOS 7` as

`/dev/mmcblk0p1    7742684         4   7742680   1% /run/media/ssuman/ANGSTROM`

I guess that the command must be passed as :-

```
./update.sh -o /run/media/ssuman/ANGSTROM
```

It's very confusing. Please also explain about the optional argument `-o` here. If possible,**please suggest me a link which I should visit to be aware of several such optional parameters**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mount point is the location within the filesystem hierarchy where a block device is mounted. In your case, `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is the block device file and `/run/media/ssuman/ANGSTROM` is the mount point.

Since it's a script file, it would be up to the script's authors/maintainers to document the command usage and optional parameters - there is no general rule about particular options.